# f.write vs print >> f

Tags: python

There are at least two ways to write to a file in python:

```
f = open(file, 'w')
f.write(string)
```

or

```
f = open(file, 'w')
print >> f, string     # in python 2
print(string, file=f)  # in python 3
```

Is there a difference between the two? Or is any one more Pythonic? I'm trying to write a bunch of HTML to file so I need a bunch of write/print statements through my file(but I don't need a templating engine).

Comment: It is pythonic to be explicit. `.write()` expresses your intent more clearly than `>>`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but with newer Python (3.x) versions print is a *function* (not a special syntax statement construct) and thus the latter will not even work on those? (I haven't really used Python since ... 2.6ish.)

Comment: @pst: very good point. All the better to use the `write()` method.

Comment: @pst: `print()` as a function allows you: `print('something', file=file)`.

Comment: @Sebastian: But it won't allow the "print chevron" form. `print >>`

Comment: @voithos: `print(.., file=f)` is the equivalent of `print >>f, ..`.

Comment: @pst: with the print function in Python 3.x you can write to file, passing one as a keyword argument to the call. No longer heterogeneous and obscure uese of ">>"

Comment: @Sebastian: I was speaking about the syntax. But I do suppose it's a moot point, since `print` as it exists in 2.x won't work at all in 3.x

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`print` does things `file.write` doesn't, allowing you to skip string formatting for some basic things.

It inserts spaces between arguments and appends the line terminator.

```
print "a", "b" # prints something like "a b\n"
```

It calls the `__str__` or `__repr__` special methods of an object to convert it to a string.

```
print 1 # prints something like "1\n"
```

You would have to manually do these things if you used `file.write` instead of `print`.

Comment: As a side note, isn't there danger, that if I write something to file using print(.., file=f), someone may break my resulting file because they might need a different string representation elsewhere? Wouldn't it be safer to just format things precisely as I want them with f.write()?

Comment: @Ibolit That's always true with shared code -- if another user changes it, it could break your use. That's what tests are for. Avoiding shared code entirely isn't a practical solution in most cases.

Comment: So f.write gives you more control over the formatting than print?

Comment: @NoName Not exactly. `write` just writes the exact string you give it. `print` attempts formatting. You can use `print` to exactly write a string too, if you want, it can just also do more. So `print` gives you more control, but `f.write` may be simpler for some cases.

Answer (score 22):

I disagree somewhat with several of the opinions expressed here, that `print >> f` is redundant and should be avoided in favour of `f.write`.

`print` and `file.write` are quite different operations. `file.write` just directly writes a string to a file. `print` is more like "render values to stdout as text". Naturally, the result of rendering a string as text is just the string, so `print >> f, my_string` and `f.write(my_string)` are *nearly* interchangeable (except for the addition of a newline). But your choice between `file.write` and `print` should normally be based on what you're doing; are you writing a string to a file, or are you rendering values to a file?

Sure, `print` is not strictly *necessary*, in that you can implement it with `file.write`. But then `file.write` is not strictly necessary, because you can implement it with the operations in `os` for dealing with file descriptors. Really they're operations on different levels, and you should use whichever is more most appropriate for your use (normally the level other nearby code is working on, or the highest level that doesn't get in your way).

I do feel that the `print >> f` syntax is fairly horrible, and is a really good example of why `print` should have been a function all along. This is much improved in Python 3. But even if you're writing Python 2 code that you're planning to port to Python 3, it is *much* easier to convert `print >> f, thing1, thing2, thing3, ...` to `print(thing1, thing2, thing3, file=f)` than it is to convert the circumlocution where you roll your own code to do the equivalent of `print`'s rendering and then call `f.write(text)`. I'm pretty sure the semi-automatic converter from Python 2 to Python 3 will even do the conversion for you, which it couldn't possibly do if you avoid the `print >> f` form.

Bottom line: use `print` to render values to stdout (or to a file). Use `f.write` to write text to a file.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @agf

I preferred `print(..., file=f)` because of its flexibility.

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('str', file=f)
    print(1, 20, file=f)
```

It is also easy to convert existing `print` command.

`write` accepts only string.

Answer (score 3):

You should not do either of those things. The most Pythonic thing to do is use the Python 3 print function (as opposed to the Python 2 print *statement*):

```
f = open(file, 'w')
print(string, file=f)
```

Of course the ideal way to do this is to just use Python 3. But if you're stuck using Python 2 you can turn it on using a [future statement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) at the top of the file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Note that this changes print in other ways, most obviously in that you need to add brackets around its arguments. But the changes are all improvments, which is the whole reason for the change in Python 3. While you're at it, consider using all the future statements to get as many backported improvements from Python 3 as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on `print` might help explain this: [print statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) (Python 2.7 documentation).

`print`, by default, prints to standard output, which in fact is a "file-like" object (`sys.stdout`). The standard output itself has a `write()` method. Using `print >> f` seems to be an unnecessary abstraction.

Also, it seems too verbose to me. `f.write()` is fine.

Comment: Are newlines ('\n') constant across all platforms? Like could I just use f.write(string + '\n') and expect a newline on all platforms?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Python does the conversions for you, by default, although this can be overridden if desired.

Comment: @agf: you are in error. By default, Python opens files in "text" mode and automates the end-of-line conversion when writing. You have to explicitly add "b" to the file open mode to have it in binary mode, with no conversions.

Comment: @agf: Have _you_ tried it? I'm running v2.6.6 on Windows XP. Writing `\n` to a file opened in text mode writes out `\r\n`. Notepad opens it fine, (as you know, it would choke on Unix file endings) and Vim displays it fine in Dos mode. If you try writing out `\r\n`, it'll write `\r\r\n`. I know it's kind of confusing with the PEPs and all, but the documentation is right on this one. Although not an authority, look at this post, too: http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10893#p50001

Answer (score 2):

As a bottonline: do use file.write when writing to files.

The ">>" idiom for printing was borrowed from C++ in Python's early days, and is rather unpythonic - so much that it no longer exists in Python 3.x  - where one can use the print, now a function instead of a statement, to write to a file - but with no special syntax for that.

As @agf points in his answer, using "print" to write to a file does more things than simply calling write - it automatically calls str(obj) to get a string representation of the object, whereas .write require that a (byte) string be passed as parameter - in Python world "explicit is better than implicit", so one more motive for one to go with file.write instead.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit" should ***NOT*** be read as "use low level operations, not higher level abstractions"!! It's the wonky syntax of the print statement that's a problem, *not* that it bundles up commonly-used-together operations into a convenient package.

Comment: "wonky syntax of the print statement", so the syntax of the print **function**  is  not wonky?

Comment: it is a funciton, using the same general rule as any other function, with absolutely no exceptional rule, and one can build a function with the very same signature out of the box, with no advanced knowledge. I guess it makes it "not wonky".

Answer (score 1):

This is the preferred way, using context handlers:

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
  f.write(string)
```

On python 2 I prefer `file.write` because the `>>` syntax is deprecated.  For python 3 you might prefer to use the print function instead, which you should note does some extra things (for example automatically convert numbers to strings for you, etc).

Comment: True but not related, you'd still need a context manager with `print >> f`