# Cannot log to a text file from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write to a text file to log data as it is being processed.  I did this in a python file and it worked fine, but when I tried from a Jupyter notebook it failed.

What worked from the python file and what I tried to use in the notebook is this:

```
f = open('./data/data_log/log'+ str(time) +'.txt', 'w')
print >> f, '#########################################'
print >> f, 'New log opened'
print >> f, '#########################################'
```

Then, in the file when a certain variable goes by I would want to write it so I can track the data as it is goes through the pipeline.  In the python file I achieved that the same way, for example:

```
# Printing this data to the file.
print >> f, 'Steering check :', steering_check
```

The '>>' seems to be unsupported because it throws an error mentioning that.

```
jupyter notebook unsupported operand type(s) for >>:
```

I was unable to find through googling and searching here a way to do this.

Can anyone here point me in the right direction, even a link to documentation or something will suffice, I just cannot located the answer showing how to do this in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use: `f.write('#######')`.

The print chevron syntax is not supported in Jupyter notebooks.

See the difference between the two syntaxes in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598228/f-write-vs-print-f).

You will have to put spaces between arguments and line terminators yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.write()` which imo looks nicer

```
f = open('./data/data_log/log'+ str(time) +'.txt', 'w')
f.write('#########################################\n')
f.write('New log opened\n')
f.write('#########################################\n')
```

And

```
f.write('Steering check : ' + steering_check + "\n")
```